# Oracle: Getting a deadlock every now and then when truncating tables in our tests

Tags: oracle, deadlock

We got ~500 of tests which run nightly on an Oracle database.

Before every test we truncate all tables with the following code:

```
    public override void EmptyTables()
    {
        const string alterConstraints = "begin for i in (select c.* from user_constraints c, user_tables u where c.table_name = u.table_name and c.constraint_type = 'R') LOOP EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || i.table_name || ' {0} constraint ' || i.constraint_name; end loop; end;";

        List<string> commandList = new List<string>();
        commandList.Add( string.Format( alterConstraints, "disable" ) );
        commandList.AddRange( GetTableNames().Select( tn => string.Format( "truncate table {0}", tn ) ) );
        commandList.Add( string.Format( alterConstraints, "enable" ) );

        ExecuteNonQuery( commandList );
    }

    public virtual void ExecuteNonQuery( IList<string> statements )
    {
        DbTransaction dbTransaction = DbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        foreach( string statement in statements )
        {
            DbCommand dbComand = CreateDbCommand( statement, dbTransaction );
            dbComand.CommandTimeout = 60 * 30;

            try
            {
                dbComand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch( Exception exception )
            {
                HandleExecuteNonQueryException( exception, dbTransaction, statement );
            }
            finally
            {
                dbComand.Dispose();
            }
        }

        dbTransaction.Commit();
    }
```

Nearly every night some (~5, random) of these tests fail at ExecuteNonQuery with either ORA-00060 or ORA-04020 deadlock (Statement: alter table SOMETABLE disable constraint FK_SOMEFK => the table and FK and disable/enable is random as well).

I know it could be very tricky to find out the problem, but might anyone out there have an idea :)

Thanks!

Comment: Most obviously somebody else is using the table. Try `ALTER SESSION SET DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 60` before you alter the tables, which gives you a waiting time up to 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Nope, did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with gathering statictics about test failures.

Before each call of `EmptyTables` method check and log results of the query:

```
select obj.owner,
       obj.object_name,
       obj.object_type,
       s.sid,
       s.serial#,
       s.status,
       s.osuser,
       s.machine
  from v$locked_object lo,
       v$session s,
       dba_objects obj
 where s.sid = lo.session_id
   and lo.object_id = obj.object_id;
```

First of all look for objects locked by sessions opened in previous test runs.

Сonsidering "random" nature of failures and repeatability of the situation, I see two suspicious possibilities:

1. If you run tests using **several sessions**, for some reason session of previous test does not have enough time to free resources. For the first time you could kill sessions found by the query, until you understand why they are not being closed properly.
2. If all tests reuse **the same session**, definetely (as mentioned in the comments) someone else plays with the schema while the tests run. But I think it's not the case, since you made fine isolated schema for test runs only: I hope you create it before start the tests and drop it after them.

To fail fast you may lock each table before DDL operaitons:

```
LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know. Currently got no rights on table v$session.